# Silverlight TextBox events to validate text input

Tags: silverlight, textinput

Hello I'm trying to handle the user's input to the TextBox in Silverlight. I need to catch the text that's been entered and if it is not valid dismiss it. I've tried processing KeyDown and TextInputStart events, but the text gets updated after them. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you better use Silverlight Validation with MVVM.

But if you prefer events, you can use the [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Event to get every new character.

You can cast the `sender` in order the get the `TextBox` and use it's `Text` property.

For example:

```
    Dim l_textBox As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    if    l_textBox.Text = "ThisIsGoodString" Then
        ... Do something ...
    End If
```

*(VB.NET code)*

Comment: But in TextChanged Event I've got only OriginalSource property in the TextChangedEventArgs.